# Setting relative layout width and height dynamically affecting childs positions inside it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have this in my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutOverlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/white_transperent80"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
            android:layout_width="94dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="ACCEPT"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRSVP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnAccept"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="RSVP by Jul 15,2015"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/txtRsvp"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here I want to set the width and height of Relative Layout with id "layoutOverlay", for that in fragment class  I have done this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RVAdapter.dipToPixels(context,HomePage.SCREEN_WIDTH), RVAdapter.dipToPixels(context,HomePage.SCREEN_WIDTH));
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        holder.layoutOverlay.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But when I do this way the childs inside this particular relative layout goes out of position. ie, btnAccept and txtRSVP goes below layoutOverlay.

Why this is happening and how I deal with it?

Here is the screen [image]

Comment: provide some screen shot

Comment: If you don't change the layout params, do the views go out of position?

Comment: No, it occupies desired positions.